# Why can a matrix without a full rank not be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I know you could just say because the $\det = 0$.

But during the introduction of determinants the professor said, obviously if two columns of the matrix are linearly dependent the matrix can't be inverted, therefore it is zero. He made it sound like it is an intuitive thing, a simple observation, but I always have to resort to the properties of determinants to show it.

How does one trivially see that you can not invert a matrix without a full rank?

Comment: You may find helpful resources [here](https://www.google.com/#q=invertible+matrix+theorem).

Comment: That is just repeating what I told you. I know about determinant properties and about characteristics of invertible matrices, I want to know about an intuitive way to see that to help think about invertible matrices

Comment: Ok. But note that 2 columns of a matrix being linearly dependent is not equivalent to the matrix having less than full rank. You may want to clarify which one you mean (and use "intuitive" since that's not the same as "trivially see[ing]").  The first implies the second but it's possible to have full rank without having only two columns being linearly dependent.  For example, $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ has less than full rank because the third column is the sum of the first two, but no two columns of $A$ are linearly dependent on each other.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Suppose that the columns of $M$ are $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and that they're linearly dependent. Then there are constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, not all $0$, with 
$$
c_1 v_1 + \ldots + c_n v_n = 0.
$$
If you form a vector $w$ with entries $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, then (1) $w$ is nonzero, and (2) it'll turn out that 
$$
Mw = c_1 v_1 + \ldots + c_n v_n = 0.  (*)
$$
(You should write out an example to see why this first equality is true). 
Now we also know that
$$
M0 = 0. (**)
$$
So if $M^{-1}$ existed, we could say two things:
$$
0 = M^{-1}0 \ (**)\\
w = M^{-1} 0\  (*)
$$
But since $w \ne 0$, these two are clearly incompatible. So $M^{-1}$ cannot exist.

Intuitively: a nontrivial linear combination of the columns *is* a nonzero vector that's sent to $0$, making the map noninvertible.

But when you really get right down to it: proving this, and things like it, help you develop your understanding, so that statements like this *become* intuitive. Think about something like "the set of integers that have integer square roots". I say that it's intuitively obvious that $19283173$ is not one of these.

Why is that "obvious"? Because I've squared a lot of numbers, and all the squares have a last digit that's either $0, 1, 4, 5, 6,$ or $9$ (because those are the last digits of squares of single-digit numbers). Now that I've told you that, my statement about "intuitively obvious" is obvious to you, too. But until you'd at least learned a little about integer squares by investigating them, your intuition wasn't as good as mine. Sometimes "intuition" is just another name for "applied experience."

Comment: This is a great answer, both addressing the claim with a rigorous proof, and suggesting intuitive ways of thinking about it to boot.

Comment: Makes me think of that great von Neumann quote to a befuddled student, "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them."

Answer (score 5):

You can think of a matrix as a linear mapping and the rank of the matrix corresponds to the dimension of the image of the mapping. So if you cut off some dimension, you can hardly lift it up back. (Imagine for example the following: a line in a plane; now you linearly transform the plane into a 1-dimensional space (a line) by projecting the plane onto, say, $x$-axis; show this to someone else - this other person cannot tell you, what the original line was, which corresponds to non-existence of the inverse map.)

Comment: That makes sense, but what about the reverse? Why can't you undo an expansion of dimensions?

Comment: @ConnorRobetorye I think the short answer is because it's not a 1:1 mapping. When projecting data from a smaller space to a larger one, assume for the sake of example that the matrix that is doing that is mxn where n<m, then there are points in the co-domain, for which there are multiple vectors x in the domain that can produce those points through the transformation provided by that matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When a matrix is not full rank there is a solution to $$Ax=0$$

Where $x$ are the coefficients that make the linear combination of columns of $A$ cancel out. (Note that this is exactly the linear combinations of columns of $A$).

Assume now that A is invertible:

$$A^{-1} A x = 0$$

But $Ix$ can not be zero (unless all coefficients are zero.)

Then the inverse can not exist when A is not full rank.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. When answering question here (especially old one), we try to find new ways of solving a problem. Your argument is already in the accepted answer.